# How to make ScrollView translucent and content behind it interactive?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a View Controller which contains a map view (*yellow* view on image) with one button. I want to add a **scroll view hover it** to "fix" the map view at background and **make content covers the map while scrolling**.

Here is the views and constraints:

[image: views]

When I run the app, the scroll view doesn't work anymore and I can't interact with the map and button because the scroll view is hover it.

What should I do to fix it and have the behaviour I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to subclass scrollView and assign that class in IB

```
class PassThroughView: UIScrollView {

 override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool { 
        return false
    }
}
```